# VMPlayer Ubuntu client automaximize screen resolution on boot

Tags: vmware

[image]

This is a minor annoyance but annoying all the same. 
I am running VMPlayer 12 on Windows 7 with Ubuntu 1510 installed as guest. I have the guest additions installed and the resolution works just fine; but everytime I reboot with the VM application maximised, it creates a small window for the client. I then have to unmaximize the player and maximize again so that the resolution stretches to fill the entire area.

I do not want to run in fullscreen mode therefore it's no option to start the VM in fullscreen mode.

**Is there some way I can force the initial client resolution when the player is maximised?**

This problem doesn't happen on VirtualBox. I have tried to move to VB but the performace is just not that great plus the buggy drag and drop make VB a no go.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off topic because questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [su].

Comment: I have added the question on Super User instead. Thanks.